# How do I check to see if a user will be redirected to his/her profile after login (Rails Tutorial Ch. 9)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm working on [chapter 9, exercise 1 of the Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users#sec-updating_deleting_exercises). I'm unsure of what to do in order to test that, after a normal login, the user will be redirected to his/her profile. The exercise's hint implies that I should modify the "successful edit with friendly forwarding" test in users_edit_test.rb in order to compare the value of session[:forwarding_url] with that of the user profile path. To do that, I added

```
assert_equal session[:forwarding_url], user_path
```

to the end of the function. However, when I do **rake test**, I get this error:

```
Expected: nil
Actual: "/users/762146111"
```

Can anyone assist me with this problem?

**Update**: Here are the controller and helper that are being tested:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
      redirect_back_or user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end

module SessionsHelper
  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Remembers a user in a persistent session.
  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

  # Returns true if the given user is the current user.
  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  # Forgets a persistent session.
  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  # Logs out the current user.
  def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end

  # Redirects to stored located (or to the default).
  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:forwarding_url] || default)
    session.delete(:forwarding_url)
  end

  # Stores the URL trying to be accessed.
  def store_location
    session[:forwarding_url] = request.url if request.get?
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to pass an argument to the `user_path` to tell it which user

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm way late in answering this question, so it might be a moot point now, but I'm working on this exercise in the tutorial right now myself and had to struggle to come up with the correct answer, but I finally did. So I thought I'd share what I did to get the tests to pass in case you're still seeking an answer. First I'll point out where the flaw in your current logic is (because I made the same mistake initially and had to process the logic flow of the code to figure out what went wrong).

In your test, you're testing for equality between with `assert_equal session[:forwarding_url], user_path(@user)`. The problem is, the user's `user_path` is never *set* as the forwarding url. In the `sessions_helper.rb` file, the `redirect_back_or()` method has this line: `redirect_to(session[:forwarding_url] || default)` (the `default` argument passed to this method is `user` when it's called in the create action of the sessions controller). So this line in the `redirect_back_or()` method can be read in plain English as

> Redirect to the forwarding url if one has been set by the `store_session` method. If the forwarding url is **nil**, redirect to the default page, which in this case is the user page.

In order to test for equality as you're trying to do (and as I initially tried), it requires that at some point `user_path(@user)` or `user` would have to be set as the session's forwarding url. `store_session` takes no parameters to do this, so the only way user_path(@user) could be set as the forwarding url is if an unauthorized user were attempting to access that page and were first forced to log in then be redirected there (as best I can tell, this text does *not* require a person to be logged in to view a single user's page). So, `user_path(@user)` would **never** conceivably be set as the forwarding url in the `store_session` method, and thusly, `assert_equal session[:forwarding_url], user_path(@user)` would **never** evaluate to true.

At this point, the error message you cited in your original question is extremely helpful in solving your problem.

```
Expected: nil
Actual: "/users/762146111"
```

If you recall from the early chapters of Hartl's text (or from the [Rails API](http://apidock.com/ruby/Test/Unit/Assertions/assert_equal)) assert_equal tests take two required parameters: the expected value and the actual value and then compare the two. This is reflected in your error message: `session[:forwarding_url]` evaluates to `nil` while `user_path(@user)` evaluates to a specific user's url. Since, like I stated earlier, the user's profile page should never conceivably be set as the forwarding url, we can eliminate `user_path(@user)` entirely from our test.

Fortunately for us, the exercise in the textbook doesn't *require* that we user `assert_equal` to get the correct result. We just need to test that `session[:forwarding_url]` has the *right value*. That should be pretty easy. Let me walk through it step by step:

1. User is not logged in and trying to access a page served via the index, edit, update, or destroy controller actions.
2. Before filter catches this and runs the `logged_in_user` method. `unless logged_in?` evaluates to false, so the code in this method is run.
3. store_location is called inside `logged_in_user` and the unauthorized user's `get` request is stored as the forwarding url. Simultaneously, the user is redirected to the log in page.
4. Assuming the user enters valid credentials to successfully log in, this calls the session controller's `create` method, to create a new session. This action logs the user in and calls `redirect_back_or()`.
5. `redirect_back_or()` checks to see if `session[:forwarding_url]` has a value associated with it -- we know it was because `store_location` assigned a value to this key in step #3. So the first half of `redirect_back_or()`'s || statement is executed and the now-authenticated user gets redirected to the page they were initially trying to access before they logged in.
6. `redirect_back_or()` then deletes the value associated with the forwarding url, since the user has been redirected there already.
7. Now we try to log in again, this time by directly accessing the log-in page. This happens successfully, and the session controller's create action is called again.
8. This time, we weren't trying to access a page we didn't have authorization to access, so the store_session method never gets called. Therefore, the forwarding_url is currently **nil**.
9. When the session is created and `redirect_back_or()` gets called, `session[:forwarding_url]` evaluates to **nil**, so the second half of the || statement gets executed, namely `redirect_to user` (since `user` is the parameter passed to the method as its default).

To summarize, **the correct value of `session[:forwarding_url]` for subsequent login attempts should be nil.** You can write this test one of two ways:

1. You can still use `assert_equal` to test for equality:

   > `assert_equal session[:forwarding_url], nil`
2. You can refactor your test to be more succinct and direct:

   > `assert_nil session[:forwarding_url]`

I prefer test #2, but I tested them both and it worked just fine both ways.

Though not explicitly required in the original exercise, I also added a test after this one to ensure all subsequent redirects are sent to the `user_path(@user)`:

> `assert_nil session[:forwarding_url]`
>       `assert_redirected_to @user`

---

---

**TL;DR:** `session[:forwarding_url]` will never equal `user_path(@user)`. If it hasn't been stored with `store_location` (which is the case with all subsequent login attempts), it will evaluate to `nil`, so a passing test for this exercise must be written one of two ways:

> `assert_nil session[:forwarding_url]`
>   **OR**
>   `assert_equal session[:forwarding_url], nil`

Comment: I read the exercise question in a different way. I thought it was saying write test to ensure when user tries to login once, fails, tries to login second time, pass, that it redirects the user to the profile page instead of edit page, rather than, tries login once, pass, tries login second time, redirect back to profile page. I was scratching my head, how can simply writing a test prevent user from going to edit page without modifying any users_controller code, that's absurd.

Comment: Also, when you said you added an extra test, after the `assert_nil session[:forwarding_url]` shouldn't you get a failure test ? Assuming I've understood you correctly, you're saying your code is `test "successful edit with friendly forwarding" do
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    log_in_as(@user)
    assert_redirected_to edit_user_path(@user)
    assert_nil session[:forwarding_url]
    assert_redirected_to @user
    name = "Foo Bar"` ? How can `assert_redirected_to @user` be a passing case when 2 lines up, you've explicitly asserted the user have just redirected to the edit profile page ?

Answer (score 3):

M. Layton's answer is correct. Just for completeness, this is the resulting green test, along with a few comments to explain the logic.

```
test "successful edit with friendly forwarding" do
    # Issue first page request.
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    # User is not logged in, so requested URL is stored in session[:forwarding_url]

    log_in_as(@user)

    # User is now logged in and should be redirected to the
    # URL stored in session[:forwarding_url].
    assert_redirected_to edit_user_path(@user)
    # sessions[:forwarding_url] should now be nil.

    name = "My Name"
    email = "email@example.com"
    patch user_path(@user), user: { name: name,
                                    email: email,
                                    password: "",
                                    password_confirmation: "" }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    @user.reload
    assert_equal name, @user.name
    assert_equal email, @user.email

    # On subsequent login attempts, user should be redirected to their profile page
    # This block is the answer to the exercise.
    assert_nil session[:forwarding_url]
    log_in_as(@user)
    assert_redirected_to user_url(@user)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the param you want to the path call such as:

```
assert_equal session[:forwarding_url], user_path(@user)
```

or whatever your user param is (current_user, etc.)

Comment: Even when I do that, I get the same error. The problem is that session[:forwarding_url] is nil. Is there something I need to be doing, such as logging out, that causes session[:forwarding_url] to have a value?

Comment: Can you post the controller you are testing?

Comment: Posted...please look in question

Comment: instead of your `assert_equal` statement in the test try `assert_redirected_to edit_user_path(@user)` or whatever your param is for user.

Comment: `assert_redirected_to user_path(@user)` works, but I feel that I am missing the point. Michael says that I need to check "for the right value of `session[:forwarding_url]`." Does `assert_redirected_to` do this?

Comment: Just saw this, did you figure this out?